# How to add a class to an element based on something saved in Local Storage with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Basically, I'm making a TODO list, the functions are save and delete records, which are already implemented and mark as important and mark as done, which are the functions that I'm having trouble with.

This is the method that I use to retrieve the items saved in Local Storage as an array.

```
function get_todos() {
    var todos = new Array;
    var todos_str = localStorage.getItem('todo');
    if (todos_str !== null) {
        todos = JSON.parse(todos_str);
    }
    return todos;
}
```

This is the method that I use to save records in Local Storage

```
function add() {
    var task = "00"+document.getElementById('task').value;
    var todos = get_todos();
    todos.push(task);
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));

    show();

    return false;
}
```

As you can see, I add the records with two 00 at the beginning, the first number is 0 when that item of the TODO list is "undone", and 1 when it is marked as done, the second number is 0 when that item if the TODO list is "not important", and 1 when it is marked as important, for changing those numbers on the local storage, I do this:-

```
//if the second digit is 0 then the task is not important
function markAsImportant(){
    var id = parseInt(this.getAttribute('id'));
    var todos = get_todos();
    var task = todos[id].replaceAt(1, "1");
    console.log(task);
    todos.splice(id, 0, task);
    todos.splice(id+1, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));
    show();

    return false;
}
```

That method is already well implemented and working as it should.

Now, knowing what item of the TODO is important and which one is not, I simply want to add a class to the items which second character is a one, and that is what I try to do here:-

```
function show() {
    var todos = get_todos();

    var html = '<div class="list">';
    for(var i=0; i<todos.length; i++) {
        //HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE
        if (todos[i].charAt(1) == '1') {
            console.log("important");
            $('.item').addClass('important');
        }
        else{
            console.log("not important");
        }

        html += '<div class="item"> <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="' + i  + '"> ' +' <div class="title">' +  todos[i].substring(2) +  '</div> <div class="tools"> <span class="tag" id="' + i  + '"> <img class="important-img" src="resources/important.png"> </span> <span class="delete remove "  id="' + i  + '"> <img src="resources/thrash.png"> </span> </div></div>';
    };
    html += '</div>';


    document.getElementById('todos').innerHTML = html;

    var deleteButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
    for (var i=0; i < deleteButtons.length; i++) {
        deleteButtons[i].addEventListener('click', remove);
    };

    var doneButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('check');
    for (var i=0; i < doneButtons.length; i++) {
        doneButtons[i].addEventListener('click', markAsDone);
    };

    var importantButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('tag');
    for (var i=0; i < importantButtons.length; i++) {
        importantButtons[i].addEventListener('click', markAsImportant);
    };

    var listItems = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
    for (var i=0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
        console.log(listItems[i]);
        $(listItems[i]).attr('id', i);
    };
}
```

But it simply won't add anything at all to the .item tags, how can I make it actually add the class important to the items that I want ?

Comment: Before your `console.log("important"); $('.item').addClass('important'); ` paste `console.log($(".item"));` and tell me what the output in console is.

Comment: In that if block but before `console.log("important");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding the html to DOM so $(".item") won't work. This should work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
  html += '<div class="item';
  if (todos[i].charAt(1) == '1') {
    console.log("important");
    html += ' important'; // The space must be there, so change just the "important" bit, but don't remove the space
  } else {
    console.log("not important");
  }
  html += '"><input type="checkbox" class="check" id="' + i + '"> ' + ' <div class="title">' + todos[i].substring(2) + '</div> <div class="tools"> <span class="tag" id="' + i + '"> <img class="important-img" src="resources/important.png"> </span> <span class="delete remove "  id="' + i + '"> <img src="resources/thrash.png"> </span> </div></div>';
}
```

Paste this instead your for loop and post the result in comments under this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help !